# AutoSuggestBox Suggestions list not closing after selection made

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

I am using C# and XAML and Template10.  I have an `AutoSuggestBox` in a command bar.  It is all working fine but the dropdown list does not close when I make my selection.  The selection activates new content that is covered up by the stuck dropdown.  It only closes if I click on the icon on the textbox, not the listed item that was selected. How is this dropdown closed programmatically in C# or XAML?

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="asb2" 
                        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                        PlaceholderText="Search for..."
                        TextChanged="asb_TextChanged"
                        QueryIcon="Find"
                        QuerySubmitted="asb_QuerySubmitted"
                        SuggestionChosen="asb_SuggestionChosen"
                        Margin="10,0"
                        Height="40"
                        MinWidth="250"
                        BorderThickness="1" />
```

Code behind:

```
private void asb_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{
    asb2.IsSuggestionListOpen = false;
    var contact = args.SelectedItem as AutoContact;
    sender.Text = string.Format("{0} *** ({1})", contact.Word, contact.Nick);
    AddressBox.Text = contact.Url;
    GoButton_Click();
}
```

Comment: Set `IsSuggestionListOpen` property to `false` can close it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I was clearing the last AutoSuggestBox text before reading the text. This kept the drop down box open because no suggestion was there to make it disappear. Moved clearing the AutoSuggestBox to OnFocus. This allowed the text to end the dropdown. When I click the AutoSuggestBox again starts empty.

Comment: Perhaps removing the `Template10` tag makes sense?